# SymPy: Can I safely differentiate atan2()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, symbolic-math

I would like to obtain a symbolic expression which is the derivative of `atan2(y,x)`, where `y` and `x` are some expressions with a variable `z`. Can I safely assume that `diff(atan2(y,x),z)` gives me what I want?

In [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989877/continuous-differentiability-of-atan2/989939#989939) there is a proof that `atan2` is continuously differentialable in (-pi,pi), but is it in SymPy?

Comment: To start with, you can't call `sympy.diff` on an expression of two variables without telling it what you want to differentiate. Also, continuously differentiable for _what_ in `(-pi, pi)`? Surely not `x` or `y`. Maybe it's continuously differentiable cutting `atan` on that range (which I think means the variable you're differentiating on is nonnegative and the other is nonzero?).

Comment: @abarnert `atan2(y,x)` is two argument function: by `y` I mean some expression, as in the case of `x`. You are right, I forgot the differentiation variable in diff!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The partial derivatives of `atan2(y, x)` with respect to `x` and `y` are computed by SymPy as

```
-y/(x**2 + y**2) 
 x/(x**2 + y**2)
```

and these expressions are continuous as long as `x, y` do not turn into zero at once. (Assuming real arguments x, y, of course - I don't think anyone puts complex numbers in `atan2`).

The above formulas are hardcoded [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/ab14b02dba5a7e3e4fb1e807fc8a954f1047a1a1/sympy/functions/elementary/trigonometric.py#L2948), so we can be very sure that SymPy will return them.